# Enabling VSYNC with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, opengl

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with a Nvidia GeForce GT 630M graphics card using the 361.42 Nvidia proprietary driver.

I am trying to enable sync to vblank for OpenGL applications, but to no avail. The output of `glxgears` runs at about 2000 FPS, for example; more importantly, my OpenGL homework assignment exhibits significant screen tearing :(

Please note that my built-in Intel GPU has vsync enabled by default.

I have looked through the forums, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. CompizConfig settings manager already has sync to vblank enabled; nvidia-settings does *not* have a sync to vblank option; and adding `export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"` to `/etc/profile` did nothing. The output of `nvidia-settings --query=SyncToVBlank --verbose` is

`WARNING: Attribute 'SyncToVBlank' specified in query 'SynctoVBlank' is not
         available on newton:0.0.`

EDIT:
It appears that Nvidia drivers do not support vsync when used in a laptop with an Intel GPU. Bumblebee can supposedly help the "cooperation" between the two GPUs, but installing `bumblebee-nvidia` resulted in very poor graphics rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's still an issue, but now it could be fixed. In short:

- kernel parameter `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` should be set;
- xserver >= 1.19;
- kernel >= 4.5;

More details here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-vsync-on-linux/60999/6